# Update combobox tpl

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

How can i update the tpl of a combobox? The store changes dynamically so the tpl should also update.

tpl.overwrite doesn't work.

```
this.getView( ).supplierCombo.setStore( suppliersStore );
var i = 1;
suppliersStore.each( function( record ) {
  if ( record.get( 'count' ) != 0 ) {
    i++;
  }
} );
var tpl =  Ext.create( 'Ext.XTemplate',
  '<tpl for=".">',
    '<tpl if="xindex == 1">',
      '<div style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 4px">'+SUSi.I18n.t( "cap_last_used" )+'</div>',
    '</tpl>',
    '<tpl if="xindex == '+i+'">',
      '<hr />',
    '</tpl>',
    '<div data-qtip="{lfr_adrz1} | {lfr_plz} {lfr_port}" class="x-boundlist-item">{text}</div>',
  '</tpl>'
)
tpl.overwrite( this.getView( ).supplierCombo, suppliersStore );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the Combo's item template is a config attribute you can just change it using combo.setTpl(myNewTemplate). I don't really understand what you are trying to do though (counting records and then inserting a hr. I don't think it should be necessary to change the template

Comment: It is necessary to change the template because the store also changes und so the count is different and therefore the <hr /> should be at another position.
Yeah, there is no setTpl method